# Can I use Sanity.io for my own data structures or just pre defined ones like 'Blog'

Tags: sanity

I've just setup a sample blog installation. I thought I would be able to define my own data structures but can't see it.

There is a settings page but I can't figure out what it is showing me

Please can someone offer me some guidance.
[image: Screenshot]

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can absolutely define your own types.

What I suspect you're missing is that there's no web UI for doing so; the Studio app, which is what you're viewing, is for editing content/data.

Sanity is JavaScript-driven, so you'll find the schemas and type definitions under the `schemas` folder in the sample app. As you edit the files under this folder, the UI will automatically reload to reflect the changes.

Comment: Amazing. Thanks. So is the Settings screen I am seeing. Presumably this is just another content structure that happens to be called Settings rather than any admin settings.

Comment: Yes, that's part of the content structure.